# Alternative to .selector property now that it is removed in jQuery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, deprecated, jquery-1.9

As of jQuery 1.9 the `.selector` property of jQuery objects has been removed. (I'm a little confused as to why, exactly). I actually use it in a few unique scenarios, and I know that I could do other things to prevent this. **Just wondering if anyone knows another way of grabbing the selector as of 1.9?**

```
$('#whatever').selector // (would of returned '#whatever')
```

One example of where I need *.selector* is when I already have a group of checkboxes by **name**, and I want to see, within that group, which one is *checked*:

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5NDBm/)**

```
var $test = $('input[name="test"]');

console.log( $test );
console.log( $(':checked', $test).attr('id') ); // returns --undefined--

console.log( 'now with .selector: ');
console.log( $($test.selector + ':checked').attr('id') ); // returns correct
```

---

> From the docs: 
>     **.selector property on jQuery objects**
>
> The remaining purpose of the deprecated .selector property on a jQuery
>   object is to support the deprecated .live() event. In 1.9, jQuery no
>   longer attempts to maintain this property in chained methods, since
>   the use of chained methods was never supported with .live(). Do not
>   use the .selector property on a jQuery object. The jQuery Migrate
>   plugin does not attempt to maintain this property.

Comment: mind providing one of those few unique scenarios? (code, not description, please)

Comment: `$('#whatever').selector` still seems to work. The documentation says *"In 1.9, jQuery no longer attempts to maintain this property **in chained methods** [...]"*. Though http://api.jquery.com/selector/ claims it was removed. I don't know, it's a bit confusing. I guess an official statement might clarify this, maybe you can post in their mailing list/forum/group/whatever.

Comment: Why not store the selector seperately?

Comment: Uhm, in your use case, that's what `.filter` is for: http://api.jquery.com/filter/. `$test.filter(':checked').attr('id')`. `$(':checked', $test)` cannot work, because `input` elements don't have any descendants.

Comment: @FelixKling damn it that does work better :/ Well shit I guess that's an easy enough alternative. Welp, that's embarrassing :)

Comment: Yeah, well, we always learn something new :)

Comment: Just put your `.filter()` thing as an example for an answer. @FelixKling

Comment: To answer Felix Kling, the official statement is quoted there and seems pretty unambiguous: **Do not use the `.selector` property on a jQuery object.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .selector property removed, workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836763/jquery-selector-property-removed-workaround)

Comment: This question was asked prior to that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be many reasons to actually *need* the original selector. In your specific use case, if you want to narrow down the set of selected elements, you can use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$test.filter(':checked').attr('id')
```

---

`$('#whatever').selector` still seems to work though. The documentation says *"In 1.9, jQuery no longer attempts to maintain this property **in chained methods** [...]"*. Though http://api.jquery.com/selector claims it was removed in 1.9. I don't know, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks! Must of been having a brainfart... overreacted that it was gone haha

Answer (score 0):

I would just save the selector in a variable like this:

```
var testSelector = 'input[name="test"]';
var test = $(testSelector);
console.log( $(testSelector + ':checked').attr('id') );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code I was working on I was able to replace

```
if ($elem.selector == 'date-column-filter')){
```

with

```
if ($elem.hasClass('date-column-filter')){
```