# jQuery .selector property removed, workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the selector used to call the current script, but of course the property I need was [removed for some reason.](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#selector-property-on-jquery-objects)

Is there a workaround for this?  Here's basically what I want to accomplish:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            console.log($(this).selector);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));

//Somwehere else:

$('.theClassISelected').myplugin();  //Should console.log('.theClassISelected')
```

I need to see `.theClassISelected` (or some form of the original selector I used to call the function) in the console, but since the selector property has been removed from jQuery, it doesn't possible anymore.

I don't understand why it was removed - I've Googled this problem for a while now and all I see are StackOverflow answers from 2011-2012 recommending the `selector` property.  I guess it was useful at some point, but not anymore?

Comment: I'm not even sure where it would be, but you can search through the jQuery 1.8 source tree for it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.8-stable

Comment: There was a discussion before. See if it helps..
[Alternative to .selector property now that it is removed in jQuery 1.9][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964760/alternative-to-selector-property-now-that-it-is-removed-in-jquery-1-9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text/501316#501316

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need the selector?

Comment: You can trace the history of this property's deprecation [in this issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1908).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> Plugins that need to use a selector should have the caller pass in the selector as part of the plugin's arguments during initialization.

http://api.jquery.com/selector/

As an aside, the docs also mention that the selector property wasn't reliable since "since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set."

Comment: Yeah, but `$('.theClassISelected').myplugin($('.theClassIsSelected'));` looks even worse to me.

Comment: @Jaxo agreed... it's ugly, I don't see another way to get access to the selector though :/

Comment: @roasted and cfs I didn't downvote, no idea where it came from.  StackOverflow said "one new answer to this post", and I clicked it to find the post insta-downvoted.  Counter-upvoted!

Comment: @Jaxo Pass a string instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: @Jaxo i didn't say you downvoted this answer, i was speaking to the anonymous downvoter ;)